# General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away LARVEL VAPOR

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, laravel-vapor

I am having this error thrown a few times "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away". It is obviously cause by the server just going down, it always restarts after a few minutes/
The vapor setup is: RDS MySQL 8.0db.t3.large50GB From what I can tell it happens if a job on the queue takes longer than 5 minutes, the server just dies.
If you could point me to the right direction or where i should look into I would very much appreciate it.
Thank you

PS I rewrote/ split/batched/moved on separate queues so that is not an issue as they should not really last that long but I am trying to figure how can I ensure it just fails more gracefully as opposed to taking the full server down if that happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your database is closing the connection after a period of inactivity as your job works on non-database tasks.

You may be able to solve this by finding the lengthy task (presumably you're doing something like data processing or video transcoding or something?) and calling [`\DB::reconnect('mysql')`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/84e27723f63fc38e4043cdcfbb5b2fccf788ef50/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php#L989) after it.